# How to get ImageView from Layout XML into BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have my image defined in an ImageView in layout XML file as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgId"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"/>
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I access ImageView object with id imgId inside my BroadCastReceiver class when I receive a broadcast?

```
public class MyIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to access layout XML elements using RemoteViews?

```
RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.mylayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for a way to modify the View objects within an App Widget. This is not possible. You can however use the RemoteViews object to change the Views within an ApWidget.

So within your BroadcastReceiver you can store some values in SharedPreferences (or any other method to persist data on disk) then [force an update of your widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#UpdatingFromTheConfiguration).

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
R.layout.example_appwidget);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, remoteViews);
```

Then within your AppWidgetProvider's onUpdate function, you can inspect the values you stored into the SharedPreferences and change the Views through the RemoteViews object. For example, there is no way to setImageMatrix on an image through a RemotrViews, but you could call setRotation.

```
remoteViews.setFloat(R.id.img1, "setRotation", 45.0);
```

**Previous answer:**

The way to get all data into a BroadcastReceiver is to include the data in the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyIntentReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra(getPackageName() + ".ImageViewId", R.id.imgId);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent );
```

This data can then be accessed when the BroadcastReceiver receives the intent.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int imgId = intent.getIntExtra(context.getPackageName() + ".ImageViewId", 0);
    ...
}
```

Comment: My bad. I edited my question. I mean to ask how can I retrieve the ImageView object in my broadcast receiver. I need to transform my ImageView something like this:                                                         `Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
matrix.postRotate((float) 30, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);`                                                            For that I need access to the imageview object.

Comment: Hmmm... Well modifying Views within a Broadcast Receiver seems a little strange; there may be a better was to achieve your goals here. Regardless, perhaps if your BroacastReceiver was an inner class within your Activity it could access an ImageView member.

Your RemoteViews question makes me think this may be for an App Widget, in which case you cannot access the ImageView within an App Widget.

Comment: I am not using an activity. Its an `AppWidgetProvider` where I register my Receiver. Even in `AppWidgetProvider`, i am unable to retrieve ImageView object.

Answer (score 0):

I found out instead of rotating an imageview i could rotate a bitmap and then set it as the bitmap for imageview.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.img);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(angle);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
updateViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imgView, bitmap);
```